# error passing const as this argument of discards qualifiers C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

how can i solve this?i dont understand where the error is
if u need i will poste the derivative class,thx for help.

```
float RifiutiP::getPrezzo()const{
    float t=1;
    float nt=0.5;
    if (mode==0)Rifiuti::setCosto(t);
    else Rifiuti::setCosto(nt) ;
    return (Rifiuti::getCosto())*(Rifiuti::getPeso());
}


36  34  C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Università\Programmazione 1\Progetti\Rifiuti\Rifiutip.cpp [Error] passing 'const Mynamespace::RifiutiP' as 'this' argument of 'void Mynamespace::Rifiuti::setCosto(float)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

this is my base class

```
#ifndef _RIFIUTI_H
#define _RIFIUTI_H
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace Mynamespace{


class Rifiuti{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &,const Rifiuti&);
    private:
    char* codice;
    int peso;
    float costo;
    public:
    Rifiuti();
    Rifiuti (const char* ,const int);
    virtual ~Rifiuti();
    Rifiuti(const Rifiuti &);
    void setCodice(const char* );
    void setPeso (const int p){peso=p;}
    const char*  getCodice ()const {return codice;}
    const int getPeso ()const {return peso;}
    virtual float getPrezzo()const=0;
    virtual const char* validita(const char *&)const=0;
    void setCosto (const float c){costo=c;}
    const float getCosto()const {return costo;}
    virtual ostream& print(ostream &)const;
};

}
#endif
```

Comment: You can't call a non-const member function (i.e. `setCosto`) from a const member function (i.e. `getPrezzo`).

Comment: @songyuanyao: Answers go down below, buddy

Answer (score 1):

Your `const` member function `getPrezzo` attempts to call the non-`const` member function `setCosto`.

This is impossible. Either the function may mutate its object, or it may not; you will have to pick one. (As a general rule, I'd say that a function `get****` shouldn't "set" *anything*.)

The compiler is doing its job by informing you that you are attempting to do something naughty.

Comment: but i cant do setCosto() const because it says: 30 42 C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Università\Programmazione 1\Progetti\Rifiuti\Rifiuti.h [Error] assignment of member 'Mynamespace::Rifiuti::costo' in read-only object

Comment: @JonasGarcia: Right, why should a "setCosto" function be `const`? How would that work? Such a function modifies the object, and `const` means "this will not modify the object".